# Woher kommt das Verb „wuppen“?

Tags: etymology, colloquial

Kürzlich habe ich das Verb „wuppen“ kennengelernt. Es steht als Jargon im [Onlineduden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wuppen) und bedeutet „etwas bewältigen“. Vor einigen Jahren hätte man eventuell noch gesagt „Wir rocken das“, und jetzt heißt es „Wir wuppen das“.

Woher stammt das Wort?

Edit: Das Revival des Wortes könnte daher kommen, dass Mitglieder der Piratenpartei das anscheinend gegenüber den Medien verwendet haben [Link 1](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/bundesparteitag-in-neumarkt-in-der-oberpfalz-was-die-piraten-wuppen-muessen-1.1668240), [Link 2](http://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/audio/audio105810.html), [Link 3](http://www.mittelbayerische.de/nachrichten/politik/artikel/piraten-beraten-ueber-ihr-wahlprogramm/914061/piraten-beraten-ueber-ihr-wahlprogramm.html).

Comment: es taucht auch bei Wilhelm Busch auf: schwuppdiwupp

Comment: Das Wort kommt aus Wuppertal und meint, etwas über die Wupper zu wuppen. Scherz beiseite: Dass Du das Wort jetzt erst kennenlernst heißt nicht, dass es erst seit kurzem im Gebrauch ist und jünger als "etwas rocken".

Comment: Um genau zu sein wollte ich nicht ausdrücken, dass das Wort neu sei, sondern nur, dass es neu in diesem Zusammenhang verwendet wird.

Comment: Ich kenne das Wort und behaupte, dass es deutlich älter ist als "rocken". Außerdem haben sie meinem Empfinden nach minimal unterschiedliche Bedeutungen: "wuppen" heißt, etwas schwieriges oder schweres mit einiger Anstrengung zu bewältigen. "rocken" heißt, es mit Begeisterung und äußerst erfolgreich zu bewältigen.

Comment: Die Behauptung, dass das Wort über die Piratenpartei verstärkt in die Öffentlichkeit gekommen sei, möchte ich so nicht unterzeichen. Ich höre das Wort seit Jahren im Kreise von Betriebswirten, Controllern, Managern und dergleichen, die sich gerne damit auseinandersetzen, wie bestimmte Aufgaben zu bewältigen sind, und die sich gerne flappsig dazu ausdrücken.

Comment: Ich kenne das Wort seit den 80er Jahren in Ost - Niedersachsen. Da hat man noch nichtmal über die Gründung der Piraten nachgedacht.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wie die [Gebrüder Grimm uns lehren](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW28744), ist es mit "wippen" verwandt und bedeutet "in die höhe schnellen, auf- und niederschwingen" oder auch "etwas mit einem ruck in die höhe heben".

Daher wird es synonym mit "etwas anpacken", "etwas bewältigen" verwendet.

Es dürfte auch schon länger als "einige Jahre" im Gebrauch sein.

Comment: Ja, aber es hat anscheinend gerade einen zweiten Frühling (siehe mein Edit).

Comment: Die Antwort rockt!

Comment: Beide, das englische Verb "to rock" als auch das deutsche "wuppen", bedeuten *schaukeln*. Das ist der Zusammenhang. Man kann sich sagen: "Das werden wir schon schaukeln."

Answer (score 7):

Zur Etymologie findet man bei den Grimms unter [wippen, *wüppen, wuppen*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW23420) noch mehr.

Offenbar handelt es sich um ein sehr altes Wort, das in vielen indogermanischen Sprachen vorkommt.

Nur als Beispiele seien hier erwähnt:

> Latein: **vibrare**, Griechisch: **γιμβάναι**, Englisch: **wipe, whip**, Schwedisch **vippa**, ...

Comment: Självklart! Ingen orsak.

Answer (score 5):

Mir ist das Wort nicht geläufig, genauso wenig wie die Redensart "mit einem Wuppdich", auf die ich über den Duden-Eintrag gestolpert bin.

Nun, die Redensart besagt, dass man etwas rasch, schwungvoll erledigt. Das Verb *wuppen* besagt, dass man etwas mit einer ruckartigen Bewegung ausführt, vor allen Dingen in die Höhe heben.

Soweit erstmal, was aus Duden und dem [Grimmschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW28744) zu entnehmen ist.

Ab da an verlassen uns leider die Onlinequellen. Der Schritt von *etwas ruckartig* ausführen hin zu *etwas bewältigen*, *etwas schaffen* muss man selbst ziehen.

So wie ich es interpretiere, ist eine Aktion, die man schnell, rasch, ruckartig ausführen kann, einfach. Eine einfache Aktion kann man bewältigen.

Nun, betrachtet man das Duden-Beispiel ("ein Projekt wuppen"), so bedeutet das dann, dass das Projekt verhältnismäßig schnell ausgeführt werden kann, folglich, dass man das Projekt bewältigen kann.

So, John Smithers hat zwar etwas schneller gewuppt, aber vieleicht hilft dir meine Antwort zusätzlich, deine Frage hinreichend zu beantworten.

Answer (score 4):

Ich kenne das ugs. "wuppen" für "etwas schaffen" bereits deutlich länger als die Kampagne der Wuppertaler Stadtwerke 2011, das erste Mal ist es mir in dieser Verwendung 2007 begegnet.

btw: Werbung greift oft auch erst auf bestehende, in Szenen gebräuchliche Sprache zurück und hebt sie damit in die allgemeine Wahrnehmung.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort wuppen feiert ein revival, seit vor ein paar Jahren die Wuppertaler Stadtwerke mit einer groß angelegten Plakataktion mit der weißen Aufschrift auf rotem Grund "Wir wuppen das" für sich als regionalen Nahversorger Werbung machten. Da die Plakate ursprünglich anonym gehalten wurden, also erstmal keiner wusste, wer oder was dahinter steckt, sorgte die Aktion für entsprechend Gesprächsstoff.
www.wirwuppendas.de

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Es ist nicht ungewöhnlich, dass Wörter erst durch Werbeaktionen wieder in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch dringen. Ob das hier auch so ist und inwieweit ein lokaler Slogan auch überregionale Beachtung fand, müsste hier allerdings noch irgendwie belegt werden.

Comment: @Takkat: Ebensowenig belegt ist bislang, dass es ein Revival des Wortes gibt und auch die Vorraussetzung dafür, dass es einen nachlassenden Gebrauch gab.

Comment: Lt. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wuppen&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwuppen %3B%2Cc0) gibt es einen jungen Boom, aber diese Daten betreffen m.W. nur Bücher, keine Zeitungen und keine mündliche Verwendung - weder in TV/Radio, noch in Gesprächen und auch keine Onlinemedien.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.typisch-dresdn.de/10-dresdner-woerter-die-zugezogene-erst-lernen-muessen/

Hier wird das Wort als typisch dresdnerisches Dialektwort ausgewiesen. Ich habe keine Ahnung, ob das stimmt, kann aber als Dresdnerin bestätigen, dass es bei uns in Gebrauch ist.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Der verlinkten Seite fehlt leider jeglicher Zeitstempel für den Wortgebrauch. Gibt es noch andere Quellen, die mehr auf die Historie achten? Denn vielleicht ist es "nur" nach Dresden eingewandert und kommt woanders her?

Answer (score 1):

"wuppen" gehört nicht zur allgemeinen Standardsprache, sondern ist typischer Jargon, wohl mehr in jugendlichen Cliquen benutzt. Ich würde vermuten, dass das Slangwort im Raum Köln/Düsseldorf vorkommt. Im süddeutschen Raum völlig unbekannt.  Den meisten Deutschen dürfte das Wort nicht geläufig sein, obwohl man vom Kontext wohl versteht, dass es "etwas fertig bringen/schaffen" bedeutet.

Answer (score -2):

Aus Wuppertal selbst: wuppen heißt in unsererm Sprachgebrauch tatsächlich:
"Kollege, pack mit an,ein Stein von 100 kilo kommt nicht von alleine aus der Wupper wieder, wo ihn Randalierer runtergeworfen haben". Nein, noch mehr: mach Pause, denk nach, lass uns eine Lösung finden, dann zusammen anpacken - und Geduld bewahren. Und dann MIT'N RUCK!
Die Idee, daß das Wort aus dem Köln/Düsseldorfer Raum kommt kann ich verneinen. Selbst in Velbert, Mettmann, (Remscheid?), Solingen und Schwelm ist das Wort praktisch unbekannt- allerdings im Oberbergischen.
Anregung: schaut mal nach "über die Wupper gehen! Kenne mindestens zwei Theorien.